# Can I connect Multiple Devices to One 5V and one GND pin of my Arduino Uno R3

Tags: wireless, robotics, arduino-uno

I have made a Bluetooth Controlled Robot Car. Using L298N Motor Driver, HC-05 Bluetooth Module and Arduino R3 I was able to run it by giving one "VIN" and one "GND" to L298N, one "5V" and one "GND" to HC-05 and I gave 12V input to the Arduino Board. 
But now I want upgrade it to an upper level by adding IR transceiver as obstacle sensor and a buzzer (as a horn, such that it will sound whenever any obstacle is sensed OR I'll set a button in the GUI to play the horn)
Please Help me. I am a very beginner and assume it as my first project.
Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can connect multiple devices to GND and +5 V. You may find that you need to bring one wire from the PCB to an external connector or piece of stripboard so that you can make more reliable connections.

Watch that your total current does not exceed the rating for the voltage regulator or USB power supply.

Comment: You can also use a breadboard to “split” the 5V and GND.